# serializeArray in jQuery live method

Tags: jquery

After filling `select` with javascript, I can't get value of that. My select is `multiple` times.
This code after clicking on save must show all items of `select` in `.live()` method.
The code is not working and I am unable to fetch all of option without clicking into option.

[DEMO VERSION](http://jsfiddle.net/pBQFF/18/)

Comment: I don't see the problem. When I select `fdsfs` and click on `save`, the alert says `[object Object]`.

Comment: i want to fetch all of option without clicking into option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can repair problem.

```
 $('#saveToDb').live("click",function(){
        $('[name="to[]"] option').prop('selected',true)
        alert($('[name="to[]"]').val())
        //alert($('[name="to[]"] option').serializeArray());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="to[]"] option')
```

will return all the options.

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/pBQFF/24/)

Comment: That's the same fiddle as before.

Comment: witch link @Barmar: i edited that. can you submit egain, :( can you edit this link: http://jsfiddle.net/pBQFF/23/ Thanks

Comment: Don't use `.serializeArray()`. That function returns the elements that would be submitted if they were in a form, so it only includes the selected options. Just use the selector by itself.